# how to add alphanumeric field in play framework

Tags: java, scala, playframework, playframework-2.5, playframework-json

i need to add alphanumeric field in play for that i am trying this code

```
object TestValidation {
  implicit val readTestUser: Reads[TestValidation] = (
    (JsPath \ "firstName").read(minLength[String](1)) and
    (JsPath \ "lastName").read(minLength[String](1)) and
    (JsPath \ "email").read(email) and
    (JsPath \ "password").read(minLength[String](1)))(TestValidation.apply _)
```

i want  the  "password" field to be alphanumeric 
i have added this custom validation constraint now i want to intregate this during Reads method of json doing something like this maybe

```
 (JsPath \ "password").read(minLength[String](1)).passwordCheckConstraint
```

i don't know the correct way to do this 
here is the constraint code

```
val allNumbers = """\d*""".r
val allLetters = """[A-Za-z]*""".r
val passwordCheckConstraint: Constraint[String] = Constraint("constraints.passwordcheck")({
  plainText =>
    val errors = plainText match {
      case allNumbers() => Seq(ValidationError("Password is all numbers"))
      case allLetters() => Seq(ValidationError("Password is all letters"))
      case _ => Nil
    }
    if (errors.isEmpty) {
      Valid
    } else {
      Invalid(errors)
    }
})
```

please help

Answer (score 0):

Having constraints represented as types is generally a very good practice:

```scala
import play.api.data.validation._
import play.api.libs.json._

class Password private(val str: String)

object Password {

  val passwordCheckConstraint: Constraint[String] = Constraint("constraints.passwordcheck")({
    plainText =>
      val allNumbers = """\d*""".r
      val allLetters = """[A-Za-z]*""".r
      val lengthErrors = Constraints.minLength(1).apply(plainText) match {
        case Invalid(errors) => errors
        case _ => Nil
      }
      val patternErrors: Seq[ValidationError] = plainText match {
        case allNumbers() => Seq(ValidationError("Password is all numbers"))
        case allLetters() => Seq(ValidationError("Password is all letters"))
        case _ => Nil
      }

      val allErrors = lengthErrors ++ patternErrors

      if (allErrors.isEmpty) {
        Valid
      } else {
        Invalid(allErrors)
      }
  })

  def validate(pass: String): Either[Seq[ValidationError],Password] = {
    passwordCheckConstraint.apply(pass) match {
      case Valid => Right(new Password(pass))
      case Invalid(errors) => Left(errors)
    }
  }

  implicit val format: Format[Password] = Format[Password](
    Reads[Password](jsv => jsv.validate[String].map(validate).flatMap {
      case Right(pass) => JsSuccess(pass)
      case Left(errors) => JsError(Seq((JsPath \ 'password,errors)))
    }),
    Writes[Password](pass => Json.toJson(pass.str))
  )
}
```

With these in place now you can write:

```scala
    (JsPath \ 'password).read[Password] //return Password instance or errors
    //or if you want to stick with the String type you can write this: 
    (JsPath \ 'password).read[Password].map(_.str)
```

Note that the `play-json`'s `JsPath.read` method accepts only a single type argument and is not the same as html form validations.