# how to add custom ValidationError in Json Reads in PlayFramework

Tags: json, scala, playframework, playframework-2.5, playframework-json

I am using play Reads validation helpers i want to show some custom message in case of json exception eg:length is minimum then specified or the given email is not valid , i knnow play displays the error message like this `error.minLength` but i want to display a reasonable message like please enter the character greater then 1 (or something ) here is my code

```
case class DirectUserSignUpValidation(firstName: String,
                                      lastName: String,
                                      email: String,
                                      password: String) extends Serializable

object DirectUserSignUpValidation {
  var validationErrorMsg=""
  implicit val readDirectUser: Reads[DirectUserSignUpValidation] = (
  (JsPath \ "firstName").read(minLength[String](1)) and
    (JsPath \ "lastName").read(minLength[String](1)) and
    (JsPath \ "email").read(email) and
    (JsPath \ "password").read(minLength[String](8).
      filterNot(ValidationError("Password is all numbers"))(_.forall(_.isDigit)).
      filterNot(ValidationError("Password is all letters"))(_.forall(_.isLetter))
    )) (UserSignUpValidation.apply _)
}
```

i have tried to add `ValidationError`like this

```
 (JsPath \ "email").read(email,Seq(ValidationError("email address not correct")) and
   but its giving me compile time error


  too many arguments for method read: (t: T)play.api.libs.json.Reads[T]
```

please helo how can i add custom validationError messages while reading json data

Comment: ```JsPath.read``` doesn't work like html form validation arguments. you asked this same question on [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44202056/how-to-add-alphanumeric-field-in-play-framework/44221781#44221781) It would be nice if you read the answer to questions that you ask...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no such thing as `(JsPath \ "firstName").read(minLength[String](1))` in play json. what  you can do with custom error message is this:

```scala
(JsPath \ "firstName")
  .read[String]
  .filter(ValidationError("your.error.message"))(_.length > 0)
```

Comment: Actually, you can do `(JsPath \ "firstName").read(minLength[String](1))` (although I also find it strange that the `String` type parameter is not given to `read`). It just does not give the custom error message.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet ```(JsPath \ "firstName").read[T](t: T)``` just returns whatever argument given as is without any validation. it's purpose is not validation but assignment of constant value. such as ```(JsPath \ "firstName").read("John")```

Comment: this is not the method I'm talking about. Rather `(JsPath \ "firstName").read[T](t: Reads[T]): Reads[T]`. `minLength[String](1)` (for which I gave signature and implementation in my answer) is a `Reads[String]` with minimal size.

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet Yes I understand. what I'm saying  is that if he writes ```(JsPath \ "firstName").read(minLength[String](1))``` playjson will resolve the firstName field as a ```Constraint[String]``` which is just wrong. hence my reply "There is no such thing as ```(JsPath \ "firstName").read(minLength[String](1))``` in play json"

Comment: Whoah, I was really slow, but I finally got what you meant! However, I tried this, and IntelliJ inferred the type as `Reads[String]`, not `Reads[Reads[String]]`, so there must be something in ambiguous method calls resolution that makes it prefer the second one in this case.

Answer (score 2):

`ValidationError` messages are supposed to be keys to be used for translation, not human readable messages.

However, if you still want to change the message for `minLength`, you'll need to reimplement it, since it is hard-coded.

Thankfully, the source code is available, so you can easily change it as you please:

```
def minLength[M](m: Int)(implicit reads: Reads[M], p: M => scala.collection.TraversableLike[_, M]) =
  filterNot[M](JsonValidationError("error.minLength", m))(_.size < m)
```

If you want to use a more generic pattern to specify errors, the only access you have is using the result from your validation. For instance, you could do

```
val json: JsValue = ???
json.validate[DirectUserSignUpValidation] match {
  case JsSuccess(dusuv, _) => doSomethingWith(dusuv)
  case JsError(errs) => doSomethingWithErrors(errs)
}
```

Or, with a more compact approach

```
json.validate[DirectUserSignUpValidation].
  fold(doSomethingWithErrors, doSomethingWith)
```